# JNA - output parameter in DLL

Tags: dll, parameters, jna, output

How can I get the output parameter, which is in a method in a C++ DLL?

```
public class MyClass {

    public int error = 0;

    public String MyMethod(){
        String str = null;

        error = error(str);

        if (error == 0){
            return str;
        }
        else
            return null;
    }

    public native int error(String outputparam);

    static {
        Native.register("MyDLL");
    }
}
```

Comment: What does the native declaration look like?

Answer (score 1):

See this [JNA FAQ entry](https://github.com/twall/jna/blob/master/www/FrequentlyAskedQuestions.md#how-do-i-read-back-a-functions-string-result), which explains how to extract a "returned" string from a buffer used as a parameter.